# What does "private" mean in "private practice", "private school" or "private hospital"?

Tags: adjectives

Specifically in Wiktionary's definition of the [word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/private#English).

Answer (score 3):

See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/private):

> 1 c (2) : carried on by the individual independently of the usual institutions
>
> > // a doctor in private practice
>
> *also* : being educated by independent study or a tutor or in a private school
>
> > // private students

In general, "private" in your three examples means "independently operated". For a private hospital and private school, in particular this means "run independently of the government".